# How to add location and description with the photo shared to be shared on facebook using Android

Tags: android, location, photo, facebook-android-sdk

I can successfully share a photo on Facebook from my Android Application using following code of Facebook SDK:

```
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                    .addPhoto(photo)
                    .build();

ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(SpecificLocationActivity.this);
shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
```

However, I would like to know how to autofill description and attach location with this photo. 
Although facebook shows these options when ShareDialog is launched, but I want it to be auto filled.

Thanks.